# What insect is in this photo?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, hemiptera

Found in Russia, in the kitchen. It is about 1–2 cm length.

[image: unknown insect]

[image: unknown insect]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an immature "True Bug", order Hemiptera. You can tell this from the general shape of the wings, and from the big "beak", a feature of the Hemiptera.

Within Hemiptera, it's possible that with those enlarged front legs, it could be an Assassin Bug, family Reduviidae.

Comment: This isn't a nymph, but a short-winged adult; enlarging the second photo shows that the front wings are not fused to the mesothorax (which would be the case in a nymph).

Answer (score 1):

It may also be a squash bug, they look pretty similar. They even have enlarged front legs too.